# What determines which player the zombardiers target?

Tags: overwatch

In Junkenstein's Revenge, there is a Zombardier enemy which attacks players with blue energy projectiles. It sometimes feels like the Zombardiers collectively 
choose a single player to shoot at for the entire game.

I've had rounds where the Zobardiers ignore me when I'm standing next to them, while other times they've gone out of their way to shoot me from across the map.

**What determines which player the Zombardiers target in Junkenstein's Revenge?**

Comment: I do believe that this is random. However, they could choose the one with lowest health or with highest ult charge. If Blizzard didn't document it somewhere, then it's probably something that should not be known to the end users

Comment: I have a sneaking feeling that damage done is taken into account, as it is rare that they attack me while playing Ana but fairly common that they focus  the McCree from across the map.

Comment: It may be something like non-ult damage done to creeps. A basic theory would be that it follows a similar threat model to their standard AIs. It does not seem to be purely most-damge dealt or even most-damage-dealt-recently.

Comment: They definitely prefer a single target until that target dies or that target is out of sight.  Which is really annoying if you're playing a healer and they decide to target you the entire game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to respond to this after this year's Halloween event.

Based on observation from a lot of games, the Zombardiers target whichever player/entity does the most damage during the first 3 mini-waves (center, left, right) and will only fire on other players if their primary target is out of line of sight or if their primary target dies. It's not clear how they choose a new target after their target dies.

This also resulted in a few interesting games where the Zombardiers targeted Torbjörn's turret until it was destroyed.

Comment: After the third mini-wave, waves start appearing at two random doors at once and will also include Zombardiers.  Well... I said random, but one wave is almost always the left (balcony) door and, in rare occurrences, you get a double-strength wave at the left door.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they work somewhat like Torbjorn's turret, attacking the first one they can shoot. Unless you get really close to them, they will then start attacking you.